# HttpClient não está baixando todo o body da pagina html

Tags: c#, httpclient

Quando tento baixar a página "https://soundcloud.com/mecaaaa" ela não baixa todo o corpo do body, logo não consigo fazer o que estou pretendendo.

Código que estou usando para pegar os dados da página.

```
public string DownloadString(string URL)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(URL).Result)
            {

                using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                {
                    return content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Alguém sabe como resolver o meu problema?
Se necessário posso colocar a parte que está sendo pega da página

Comment: Qual o proposito?

Comment: O que você tá tentando pegar? Aqui carregou normalmente, tem que ver se o que você quer carregar está de fato na requisição que você está utilizando, a página não trás tudo de forma monolítica, tem que ser observadas as requisições.

Comment: @LucasMiranda estou tentando pegar o link das musicas que estão na pagina, porem esse links não aparecem no html que o código recebe

Comment: Olhando de relance aqui da pra ver que esses dados tão vindo de uma requisição nesse endpoint aqui: https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/stream/users/
você vai precisar dar uma olhada em como ele manda os parametros e emular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifique se os links que você está procurando não são carregados com JS, ou seja, depois do load da página. Caso isso ocorra, você não conseguirá pegar os elementos HTML usando HttpClient, pois ele não processa JS.